# How to build match query to search in path string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have faced with elasticsearch for the first time. Elasticsearch is used with SVN.

I need to find commits to a specific folder. For example there are two branches:

1. /branches/0.10.2/....
2. /branches/0.10.2-hotfix/....

Such query

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "indices": {
            "indices": [
              "5439ce1e-e92f-4759-b0c0-3a753b1703b6"
            ],
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "range": {
                      "revision": {
                        "from": 413493,
                        "to": 415000
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "span_first": {
                      "match": {
                        "span_term": {
                          "path": "branches"
                        }
                      },
                      "end": 1
                    }
                  },
                  {                                  _
                    "match": {                        |
                      "path": "0.10.2-hotfix"  <------|
                    }                                 |
                  }                                  _|
                ]
              }
            },
            "no_match_query": "none"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

returns me commits in both folders.

How to find commits exactly to *0.10.2* or *0.10.2-hotfix*?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `match_phrase` (which is a syntactic sugar for a subtype of `match`):

```
{
   "query":{
      "bool":{
         "should":[
            {
               "indices":{
                  "indices":[
                     "5439ce1e-e92f-4759-b0c0-3a753b1703b6"
                  ],
                  "query":{
                     "bool":{
                        "must":[
                           {
                              "range":{
                                 "revision":{
                                    "from":413493,
                                    "to":415000
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "span_first":{
                                 "match":{
                                    "span_term":{
                                       "path":"branches"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 "end":1
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "match_phrase":{
                                 "path":"0.10.2-hotfix"
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "no_match_query":"none"
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It works for *0.10.2-hotfix* but for *0.10.2* it returns commits to both folders.

Comment: I think it need to use slashes. But {"match_phrase":"path":"/0.10.2/"} does not changes anything. It still returns commits to both folders.

Comment: I think for this you might need to create a "non analyzed" mapping for this field. http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html

Comment: Thanks! *0.10.2-hotfix* tokenized into *0.10.2* and *hotfix*. That's why. I  will try to use new index with new mapping for *path*